# IntelliJ IDEA 2017.3.4 - Change color of comments

Tags: intellij-idea, colors

I installed plugin **Material Theme UI** and I'm using **Material Darker** color scheme. I don't like a color of comments and I'd like to change it in whole editor.

When I go to **Settings -> Editor -> Color Scheme -> General** there is no option to change the color of comments. Is it possible to change this setting to whole editor or I have to manually change it in each programming language setting in Color Scheme?

Answer (score 8):

You can set the color separately for each language, but it is not necessary. By default each language setting inherits from `Settings | Editor | Color Scheme | Language Defaults | Comments`, and you can change it there.

Comment: I've tried but this property is overriden by specific language settings